# DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.LongTimePattern not updating

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, region

I am using this to read the current long time pattern in Windows:

```
System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.LongTimePattern
```

However, if I make a change in the regional settings in the Control Panel, this pattern isn't updated until I restart my application. How can I force this pattern to update when the regional settings are changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values are cached.  There is a method to clear this.  `CultureInfo.ClearCachedData()`.

Side note: back in the days of .NET 1.x, this method didn't exist.  You had to use reflection to null out the private field.  Good times :)